# In Flex, how should properties be passed to child components?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I'm new to Adobe Flex, and am working on a desktop Air application. The jist of my problem is figuring out how a child component can be aware of one of its parents properties. The parent might be more than one level up.

Here's a simplified example to illustrate.

I have a custom component that is made up of a few child components, in the example there is only a single button. I have several instances of this custom component next to each other. When one of the child buttons is pressed, I want to generate an event that lets another part of my application know which instance of the custom component the button belonged to. I understand how to create custom events, so I left that part out of the sample code.

My current approach involves creating a property, (e.g. a "position" integer) that I assign to each of the parent components in mxml. The children components also have the position property, which is set to match the parent when the "preinitialize" event occurs. According to the component lifecyle, the preinitialize event occurs in parent components first, then goes down the line of children. Is this safe? Or is there a better way to do this?

Using data binding seems a waste of resources, because the position property never changes after the application loads.

Here are some relevant code snippets.

main.mxml

```
<s:VGroup>
    <components:CustomComponent position="0"/>
    <components:CustomComponent position="1"/>
    <components:CustomComponent position="2"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

CustomComponent.mxml

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        public var position:int;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<components:CustomButton 
    preinitialize="(event.target as CustomButton).setPosition(position)"/>
```

CustomButton.mxml

```
<s:Button>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public var position:int;

            public function setPosition(position:int):void
            {
                this.position = position;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    
</s:Button>
```

Comment: Try with bubbling events between father and child, that's the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"how a child component can be aware of one of its parents properties."

```
-> this.parent.propertyName;
```

The parent might be more than one level up.
-> Then it is not a parent, but an ancestor. You might need to go up the parent chain. this.parent.parent.

Also look into this.document and this.owner. For list based controls these mean different things.

Finally, Look into event bubbling. Sounds like you want your events to bubble up to your top level container.

Comment: Though technically possible, I reckon this is very, very bad advice. A component should **never** now about its ancestors. I wish the `parent` property would die, but I guess it's there for legacy/performance reasons. (bubbling) events are indeed the way to go for child-parent communication.

Comment: I agree with indicating RIAstar, bubbling events are the way to go. I can not give an example because it can vary depending on the implementation so that it becomes useless. -

Comment: Agreed- although I was only answering the question, not giving advice.  The final statement about events was the advice.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. "this.parent" access might be the direct answer but I'm going to take your advice and go for event bubbling instead. Thank you for not taking my question too literally.

Comment: Here's my understanding, correct me if I'm off. 

I let child event (e.g. button click) bubble up to the parent. Whenever the parent receives the event from the child, it sends a custom event that includes the parent's position.

Then other parts of my application can listen for the parents custom event.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is where a framework/microarchitecture comes into play.  You have to keep in mind, that the Flex/Adobe Air library is first and foremost a component library.  That means you don't get anything out of the box to help with things such as communication between different part of the app.  Sometimes folks will try to use the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to manage dependencies, but I can tell you from experience that is a horrible mistake that will cost you in the long run as the code becomes very brittle and fragile with high [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

Nowadays, there are many frameworks designed to help you with the problem and others that you have and will face.  A list of these frameworks can be found through Google, but [Swiz](https://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Home), [Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com/), [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) and [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/) is a great starting point.

There are other frameworks that you may run across such as Cairngorm and PureMVC.  Those are generally termed "first generation" frameworks.  Personally, I shy away from those because they feel a little too heavy an intrusive.

Comment: I disagree that Flex is "first and foremost a component library". With the Spark architecture + two-way databinding, Flex 4 brings a very nice MVwhatever to the table; no bloated MVC libraries required. The only thing it lacks is an IoC container (I use SwiftSuspenders for that). That said, I seem to be part of a minority to have this opinion.

Comment: @RIAstar I see the two-way binding as more of a footnote.  Of course its the core of pretty much every Flex MVC framework out there, but its the declarative UI that keeps people coming.